# Windows 10 Access denied

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have some important files on my PC, and it crashed. I tried to repair it but it didn't fix the issue. I installed Windows into another partition, hoping to gain access to the old Windows partition to recover the files, but I get "Access Denied". How can I fix this?

Comment: Take ownership and then grant yourself full or modify access from the top level all the way down.

Answer (score -2):

Log in as administartor and follow the steps:

1. Right-click on a file or folder with restricted files.
2. Select Properties.
3. Click the Security tab.
4. Click Advanced.
5. Click "Change" next to the owner name.
6. Click Advanced.
7. Click Find Now.
8. Select your username and click OK.
9. Click OK.
10. Click Apply ticking "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"
11. Click OK.
12. Now "add" below "Permission entries"
13. Click Select a principal.
14. Click Advanced.
15. Click Find Now.
16. Select your username and click OK.
17. Tick on "Full permissions"
18. Click OK.

Detailed guide - https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer

Comment: Answers that only contain a link are not considered helpful to the community.